# Spring cloud stream - implement idempotent consumer

Tags: spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka, spring-cloud-stream-binder

I am using spring cloud stream functional approach and looking for implementing idempotent consumer behavior.

Is there any configuration which can be set to handle duplicate messages